# How to find intersections of two lines

Tags: java

I'm Suppoused to write a class with a constructor for a **Point** and a **Line** and in the Line class I'm suppoused to write a method that finds if two lines intersect or not. This is my Point class:

```
public class Point {
static double x;
static double y;

public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

This is my Line Class

```
public class Line {

public Line(Point x, Point y) {
}

// create two points for a line
static Point x1y1;
static Point x2y2;

// create another two points for another line
static Point x3y3;
static Point x4y4;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create lines
    Line line1 = new Line(x1y1, x2y2);
    Line line2 = new Line(x3y3, x4y4);

    //initialize points
    x1y1 = new Point(1.0, 1.0);
    x2y2 = new Point(3.0, 3.0);
    x3y3 = new Point(1.0, 2.0);
    x4y4 = new Point(4.0, 2.0);

    //call method to find if lines intersect
    findIntersection(line1, line2);
    System.out.println(x1y1.x);
}

public static void findIntersection(Line line1, Line line2) {
    double denominator = (x1y1.x - x2y2.x) * (x3y3.y - x4y4.y)
            - (x1y1.y - x2y2.y) * (x3y3.x - x4y4.x);
    double px = 0;
    double py = 0;

    if (denominator == 0) {
        System.out.println("Lines are parallel, they do not intersect");
    } else {
        px = ((x1y1.x * x2y2.y - x1y1.y * x2y2.x) * (x3y3.x - x4y4.x) - (x1y1.x - x2y2.x)
                * (x3y3.x * x4y4.y - x3y3.y * x4y4.x))
                / denominator;
        py = ((x1y1.x * x2y2.y - x1y1.y * x2y2.x) * (x3y3.y - x4y4.y) - (x1y1.y - x2y2.y)
                * (x3y3.x * x4y4.y - x3y3.y * x4y4.x))
                / denominator;

        System.out.println(px + "," + py);

    }
}
```

}

The problem is I initialize all the points so that the lines should intersect, but when I try to print out the values of the points, the values of the x-es and y-s of the firss 3 points are equal to the 4th one although I'm initializing them with different values and thus the method calcutes that the lines do not intersect. Why are the values of the first three y and x equal to the 4th?

Comment: Your line constructor is empty, so your "line" is actually... nothing and findIntersection uses lines as parameters but never uses lines, just the static ints you declared. What x and y are you refering to when you say "first three equal to the 3th"?

Comment: Hmmm. I could probably fix it and use it to find strongholds.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `x` and `y` of `Point` class are `static`. It means, every instance of `Point` class will use the same values. Remove `static` to fix it.

```
public class Point {
double x;
double y;
```

You should improve the class design too anyway: Two classes (Point, Lines) another with main method.

The same for Line too. Or you will end up with the same Points for every line. (You avoited this using 4 variables i think.)

---

Something like this

```
public class Point {
    double x;
    double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class Line {
    Point a;
    Point b;

    public Line(Point a, Point b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Point itIntersect(Line line) {
        // here change the logic
        Point point = null;

        double denominator = (x1y1.x - x2y2.x) * (x3y3.y - x4y4.y)
                - (x1y1.y - x2y2.y) * (x3y3.x - x4y4.x);

        double px = 0;
        double py = 0;

        if (denominator != 0) {
            px = ((x1y1.x * x2y2.y - x1y1.y * x2y2.x) * (x3y3.x - x4y4.x) - (x1y1.x - x2y2.x)
                    * (x3y3.x * x4y4.y - x3y3.y * x4y4.x))
                    / denominator;
            py = ((x1y1.x * x2y2.y - x1y1.y * x2y2.x) * (x3y3.y - x4y4.y) - (x1y1.y - x2y2.y)
                    * (x3y3.x * x4y4.y - x3y3.y * x4y4.x))
                    / denominator;

//            System.out.println(px + "," + py);

            point = new Point(px, py);

        }

        return point;
    }
}
```

P.S I didn't changed the logic of intersect because it's too long, but you could do something like this to improve the design.

Then you need to do Point point = line.itIntersect(anotherLine);

If it's null it don't intersect, else it will return the point.

P.S Make `x` and `y` private, i didn't because it was an example.

Comment: Why is it also practice using the System.out class in this case (I was taken points because of it) ?

Comment: You will use System.out to print in the console the point of intersection.